# How can I properly use my fingerprint scanner?

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, scanner

I just bought a Thinkpad T430 and installed Linux Mint 19 (basically ubuntu) on it. It's the first time ever I use linux so I'm kinda lost. I searched a bit and I found a way to make the built in fingerprint scanner work. I installed a program called fingerprint gui that works pretty ok, but only for the lock screen and the terminal. It doesn't actually prompt me to use the scanner for any other of the os requests for a password, like accessing secure folders or installing/opening some program. How can I make it so I always have the alternative of using the scanner whenever a password promt pops up?

Comment: This site offers support only for [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours). *Linux Mint*, even though it's based on Ubuntu, is off-topic here but questions about it are welcome at our related site: [unix.se].

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for redirecting, but wouldn't the functionality be basically the same? Since Mint is based on Ubuntu it should, and already does work pretty much like it in 99% of cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ambit of *this* site is official flavors. So even my favorite "distro", KDE Neon, is off-topic here.

Comment: @DKBose Sadly, I can only post once evert 40 minutes so I'll have to wait to get an answer there. In the meantime, do you have any info on how can I proceed with this? I'd be very glad.

Comment: The thing is that distros do make changes from what they're based on or derived from. So, there is a chance things could be different. Even among the "official" flavors, what works in one may not apply to another. By the way, the [official Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/) is pretty active. And my laptop doesn't have a fingerprint scanner so I'm of no help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things like the keyring need the password as a decode key, so the fringerprint reader cannot do the job. Since my email passwords are stored in the keyring, even after logging in with my fingerprint reader, I have to enter a password to read email.  I decided just to skip using the fingerprint reader entirely.

Comment: Is there an alternative? I would really like to use it.